# Login with Facebook in .NET MAUI

Tags: android, webview, facebook-login, maui

I'm creating a simple .Net MAUI app which opens my web page on launch using android's WebView.

My web page is protected with a "Login with facebook" feature which works well, however Login with facebook [no longer supports web views - it was deprecated.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/deprecating-webviews)

I don't want my app to open up a browser using Chrome's custom tabs because then it will be apparent to the end user that the app is just opening up a browser, when I'm trying to replicate a native experience.

So what's the best practice to tackle this? Maybe it could just launch facebook's SSO in the Chrome custom tab, and then pass the auth token back to the webview after login somehow? Anyone got any guidance to help with this?

Comment: *"because then it will be apparent to the end user that the app is just opening up a browser,"* [SPECULATION] I'm not an expert, but I fear what you want may have been lost. Details: Facebook needs to alleviate a "phishing" problem, where a malware app can try to convince users they are seeing a "Facebook login" page, when they aren't. Thus getting people to enter their login info. If Facebook forces the redirect to browser, then only malware will still show (simulated) Facebook login; users can be taught to delete such apps.

Comment: Yeah fair, I get that, I guess I'm just wondering if there's a recommended way to tackle the problem. Maybe a separate "Login with facebook" journey, but then is it easy to pass the auth tokens to the web view?

Comment: Unfortunately, that is beyond my experience. Not sure where those auth tokens are held, when the browser is the front end. Looks like others who read this also overlooked that part of your question. Please make a new question, and focus it on that approach. To avoid getting closed, add the code with which you launch the browser, then explain that you need to get auth token back from facebook and/or the browser. Word that question differently enough that it doesn't get closed as a dup of this. Include a link back to this, and explain that no one responded to *that part* of the question.

Comment: Title something like "Can app get Facebook auth token back from Facebook browser login?" If you have a server that helps support your app, mention that. Might be some option that way (though I haven't thought of a way). Most apps do a server-based login. Firebase can help with that, if you don't have your own server. That doesn't get user logged into Facebook however, so if they then tell app to post something to Facebook, they have to log in there too. Hmm, that's another avenue to pursue. There must still be a way for an app to post to user's wall/feed, by having them log in to Facebook.

Comment: Hi, have you managed to find a way to login to Facebook with MAUI?